# Json Converted array is a string?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I've converted an array inside c# to json (This ugly escaping bahh). Loaded it into javascript. Should be an array. Right now it's a string. How to solve this. What is wrong here ?

```
["\u003cdiv\u003e\u003ch1\u003eText\u003c/h1\u003e\u003cp\u003eText. Text\u003cbr/\u003eText changes and Text\u003cbr/\u003eText\u003cbr/\u003ebase.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003ch1\u003eRequirements\u003c/h1\u003e\u003cp\u003e.Text Text\u003c/p\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003ch1\u003eLicensing\u003c/h1\u003e\u003cp\u003eFree / Text\u003c/p\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003ch1\u003eDownload\u003c/h1\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027Text\u0027\u003eZIP-Archiv,  Text\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e",
"\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cvideo poster=\u0027./Image/poster.png\u0027 controls\u003e\u003csource src=\u0027./Content/Video/video.mp4\u0027 type=\u0027video/mp4\u0027\u003e\u003c/video\u003e\u003c/div\u003e"]


[{"Content":"[\"\\u003cdiv\\u003e\\u003ch1\\u003eText\...
```

Comment: Do you have the correct content-type when you send the json data from the server? Did you parse the string to object on the javascript side?

Comment: Looks like a valid JSON, can you post your JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to deserilize it.

```
var array = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
```

Comment: here `array` variable will be your object

Comment: it worked. Just saw the plain text.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your using jquery for an ajax request to your c# function, you would use the following code. The key here is to use datatype 'json' so jquery returns the string in your expected format. Then iterate over the array

```
         $.ajax({
                url: '/Controller/Action',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    Variable: 'value'
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (i, row) {

                        alert(data[i])

                    });                      

                });
```